# if there is any close button is available in android?

Tags: android, button

"x" button is available or not in android,if no instead of that what button is used?

Comment: You don't close apps on Android. If anything, you switch to a different app, or the home screen. Also, this is not a programming-related question. Try android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you speak up a little bit?

Comment: @downvoters: Don't just vote down! Comment or answer to explain! @user538626: you should consider to write a real comment... your comment is in the most optimistic way a waste of characters.

Comment: @ebomike hai    
Can you speak up a little bit?

Comment: Writing useless comments is a great way to get your account flagged and eventually banned. Don't waste our time, please. We're trying to help.

Comment: @ebo comments are for useless stuff.  As long as it isn't abusive or trolling they're fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [Multitasking the Android Way](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html) - I had a close menu in my Apps and I removed them after reading the article. As others pointed out: you should not have a close button or close menu in Android.